# Activeadmin takes angular js routes, not rails routes

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have an existing app with `Rails 3.2.17` and angular js. I would like to include Activeadmin in the existing app.

I followed the steps from [active-admin post from ryan bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin?view=asciicast).
I performed following processes:

1. Added `gem activeadmin` in Gemfile
2. Run `bundle install`
3. `rails g active_admin:install --skip-users` (as I already have devise)
4. Run `rake db:migrate`
5. Restart the server

I have following routes if I run `rake routes`:

```
          admin_root             /admin(.:format)                                                           admin/dashboard#index
          admin_dashboard GET    /admin/dashboard
```

When I go to `localhost:3000/admin`. The page is redirected to the angular home page, which has following code:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

I could add the view of activeadmin to the routes of angular, but it doesn't have any view but only `app/admin/dashboard.rb`, which is rendered by application.html.erb in rails application. But, I do not have application.html.erb as my application is mostly based on angular.js. Can anyone help me with this issue about how I can skip the angular routes and take up the rails route for rendering activeadmin page?

Comment: Did you run `rake db:migrate` after `rails g active_admin:install --skip-users`?

Comment: Yes, I did run `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: This example on [angular routing](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating#configure-routes-and-views) might help you. BTW, I don't understand the config of your rails app around your view-less dashboard... Maybe your project does not fit Activeadmin's expected project structure?

Comment: this question lacks the angular configuration....please specify how you connect your angular part to rails.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add activeadmin to your angular routes, it's fine to have a combination of angular routes and rails routes. Angular routes by default have a '#', whilst rails routes don't. One possibility is that you have tried to beautify your angular routes by removing the '#' as covered here https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

If that is what you have done it may mess with the rails routes.